# How to add logo at exam class with two column?

Tags: floats, two-column, exam, logos

I have a problem about "How to add logo at Exam class with two column ?".

My MWE like this :

```
\documentclass[11pt,addpoints,answers,twocolumn]{exam}
\usepackage{graphicx,lastpage}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb} % rumus
\newcommand\mylog[1]{\mathop{{}^{#1}\mathrm{log}}}
\hyphenpenalty 10000
\usepackage{geometry}
\flushbottom
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\renewcommand\ULthickness{2pt}   %%---> For changing thickness of underline
\setlength\ULdepth{1.5ex}%\maxdimen ---> For changing depth of underline
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}
\pagestyle{empty}

\pagestyle{headandfoot}
\headrule
\newcommand{\continuedmessage}{%
\ifcontinuation{\footnotesize Question \ContinuedQuestion\ continues\ldots}{}%
}
\runningheader{\footnotesize Physcis}
{\footnotesize Physics --- Sixth semester}
{\footnotesize Page \thepage\ of \numpages}
\footrule
\footer{\footnotesize Student's name:}
{}
{\ifincomplete{\footnotesize Question \IncompleteQuestion\ continues
on the next page\ldots}{\iflastpage{\footnotesize End of exam}{\footnotesize Please go on to the next page\ldots}}}
%
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{figure}{figure}{figures}
\crefname{question}{question}{questions}
%
%
%==============================================================
\begin{document}
%%
%% \thispagestyle{empty}
%
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[l]{.1\textwidth}%
\noindent
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{minipage}%
%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[r]{.68\textwidth}%
\begin{center}
 {\large \bfseries DEPARTMENT OF PHYSICS \par
 \Large Institute\\[2pt]
 \large Subject {(\normalsize Sixth semester)}  \par}
%  \vspace{0.5cm}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}%
%
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[l]{.175\textwidth}%
\noindent
{\bfseries Your name}\\
Professor\\
{\footnotesize Date: {17.01.2013}}
\end{minipage}}%
%
\par
\noindent
\uline{Time: 1 hour   \hfill \normalsize\emph{\underline{Internal Assessment test - I}} \hfill        Maximum Marks: 20}
%

\begin{questions}

\question Dua kg jeruk dan tiga kg apel harganya Rp $45.000,$-. Lima kg jeruk dan dua kg apel hargannya Rp $52.000,$-. Harga satu kg jeruk dan satu kg apel sama dengan \begin{choices}
\choice Rp $6.000,$-
\choice Rp $9.000,$-
\choice Rp $11.000,$-
\choice Rp $17.000,$-
\choice Rp $20.000,$-
\end{choices}
\question Jika garis $(a+b)x+2by=2$ dan garis $ax-(b-3a)y=-4$ berpotongan di $(1,-1)$ maka $a+b=$
\begin{choices}
\choice $-2$
\choice $-1$
\choice $0$
\choice $1$
\choice $2$
\end{choices}
\question Pertaksamaan $\frac{4\sqrt{x}}{x^2+3}\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ mempunyai penyelesaian \begin{choices}
\choice $1\leq x \leq 3$
\choice $1\leq x \leq \sqrt{3}$ atua $x\geq 3$
\choice $x\leq 1$ atau $x\geq 3$
\choice $0\leq x \leq 1$ atau $x\geq 3$
\choice $0\leq x\leq 1$ atau $x\geq 3$
\end{choices}
\question Nilai maksimum untuk $z=6x+3y-2$ yang memenuhi sistem pertaksamaan
\begin{eqnarray*}
x+2y &\leq& 4 \\
x-y &\leq& 2\\
x+y &\geq& 1 \\
x\geq 0, y&\geq& 0
\end{eqnarray*}
adalah
\begin{choices}
\choice $4$
\choice $10$
\choice $13$
\choice $16$
\choice $19$
\end{choices}
\question Dalam suatu deret aritmatika, jika $U_3+U_7=56$ dan $U_6+U_{10}=86$, maka suku ke-$2$ deret tersebut adalah
\begin{choices}
\choice $8$
\choice $10$
\choice $12$
\choice $13$
\choice $15$
\end{choices}

\end{questions}

 \begin{center}
  \rule{.5\textwidth}{1pt}
 \end{center}
\end{document}
```

And you can see the result like this : 
[image: ER]

But, I want the result likes this :

[image: RE]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[11pt,addpoints,answers,twocolumn]{exam}
\usepackage{graphicx,lastpage}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb} % rumus
\newcommand\mylog[1]{\mathop{{}^{#1}\mathrm{log}}}
\hyphenpenalty 10000
\usepackage{geometry}
\flushbottom
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\renewcommand\ULthickness{2pt}   %%---> For changing thickness of underline
\setlength\ULdepth{1.5ex}%\maxdimen ---> For changing depth of underline
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}
\pagestyle{empty}

\pagestyle{headandfoot}
\headrule
\newcommand{\continuedmessage}{%
\ifcontinuation{\footnotesize Question \ContinuedQuestion\ continues\ldots}{}%
}
\firstpageheader{}{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=1cm]{example-image-a}}{}
\runningheader{\footnotesize Physics}
{\footnotesize Physics --- Sixth semester}
{\footnotesize Page \thepage\ of \numpages}
\footrule
\footer{\footnotesize Student's name:}
{}
{\ifincomplete{\footnotesize Question \IncompleteQuestion\ continues
on the next page\ldots}{\iflastpage{\footnotesize End of exam}{\footnotesize Please go on to the next page\ldots}}}
%
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{figure}{figure}{figures}
\crefname{question}{question}{questions}
%
%    
%==============================================================
\begin{document}

%%
%% \thispagestyle{empty}
%
\noindent
\uline{Time: 1 hour   \hfill \normalsize\emph{\underline{Internal Assessment test - I}} \hfill        Maximum Marks: 20}
%

\begin{questions}

\question Dua kg jeruk dan tiga kg apel harganya Rp $45.000,$-. Lima kg jeruk dan dua kg apel hargannya Rp $52.000,$-. Harga satu kg jeruk dan satu kg apel sama dengan \begin{choices}
\choice Rp $6.000,$-
\choice Rp $9.000,$-
\choice Rp $11.000,$-
\choice Rp $17.000,$-
\choice Rp $20.000,$-
\end{choices}
\question Jika garis $(a+b)x+2by=2$ dan garis $ax-(b-3a)y=-4$ berpotongan di $(1,-1)$ maka $a+b=$
\begin{choices}
\choice $-2$
\choice $-1$
\choice $0$
\choice $1$
\choice $2$
\end{choices}
\question Pertaksamaan $\frac{4\sqrt{x}}{x^2+3}\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ mempunyai penyelesaian \begin{choices}
\choice $1\leq x \leq 3$
\choice $1\leq x \leq \sqrt{3}$ atua $x\geq 3$
\choice $x\leq 1$ atau $x\geq 3$
\choice $0\leq x \leq 1$ atau $x\geq 3$
\choice $0\leq x\leq 1$ atau $x\geq 3$
\end{choices}
\question Nilai maksimum untuk $z=6x+3y-2$ yang memenuhi sistem pertaksamaan
\begin{eqnarray*}
x+2y &\leq& 4 \\
x-y &\leq& 2\\
x+y &\geq& 1 \\
x\geq 0, y&\geq& 0
\end{eqnarray*}
adalah
\begin{choices}
\choice $4$
\choice $10$
\choice $13$
\choice $16$
\choice $19$
\end{choices}
\question Dalam suatu deret aritmatika, jika $U_3+U_7=56$ dan $U_6+U_{10}=86$, maka suku ke-$2$ deret tersebut adalah
\begin{choices}
\choice $8$
\choice $10$
\choice $12$
\choice $13$
\choice $15$
\end{choices}

\end{questions}

 \begin{center}
  \rule{\columnwidth}{1pt}
 \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I have just added a line

```
\firstpageheader{}{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=1cm]{example-image-a}}{}
```

in the definitions of `\pagestyle{headandfoot}`.

Comment: I think you can put it on the first page header. See what I have made [here](http://menulislatex.blogspot.com/2015/05/exam-membuat-naskah-soal-ujian.html) (in the second example of document).

Comment: @kalakay It is on first page header here isn't it?

Comment: Yes, I put it on the first page header. I think it does not matter with the body in two columns.

Comment: @kalakay , I think solution from Harish Kumar is better